# How to delete selected Item from collection view in .net MAUI

Tags: .net, maui

I have collection in my Child view.

```
 <CollectionView  SelectionMode="Single" SelectedItem="{Binding Source={Reference sideview}, Path=myViewModel.SelectedItem.FileName}"
                     ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Reference sideview}, Path=myViewModel.Items }" >
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate >
                <Grid>
                <Label Text="{Binding FileName}"   VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>
```

I want to delete selected item
My parent view where I have delete button

```
      <Button x:Name="BTN_REMOVE_FILE"  Text="Remove" Command="{Binding DeleteCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem}" >
```

I have created delete command in my viewmodel

```
   [RelayCommand]
    public void Delete(Data s)
    {
        if (Items.Contains(s)) {
            Items.Remove(s);
        }  
    }
```

and from view I have pass the command parameter from view like this

I also have created selectedItem in my view Model

```
 public Data selectedItem;
    public Data SelectedItem
    {
        get
        {
            return selectedItem;
        }
        set
        {
            if(selectedItem != value)
            {
                selectedItem = value;
            }
        }
    }`public MyViewModel()
    {

        Items = new ObservableCollection<Data>();
        selectedItem = new Data();
    }
    `
```

It is showing me exception like **Parameter "parameter" (object) cannot be of type DemoApp.MVVM.ViewModel.MyViewModel, as the command type requires an argument of type DemoApp.MVVM.Model.Data. (Parameter 'parameter')**

Tried to add this in my viewModel  `public Data Name { get; set; }`

view     `<Button x:Name="BTN_REMOVE_FILE"  Text="Remove" Command="{Binding DeleteCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding Name}" >`

Comment: you are passing in the entire VM as the `CommandParameter` instead of just the selected item.

Comment: then what should I pass there ??

Comment: I have also created one property of Data in viewModel and then binded it in view still it is not woking

Comment: I have updated my code can youplease check once ? @Jason

Comment: your `Command` expects a parameter of type `Data`.  You have not posted any of your VM code so it's impossible to offer any concrete advice.  If your `CollectionView` is binding the `SelectedItem` property, then my guess is that is what you should use.

Comment: Add to question the xaml declaration of the `CollectionView`. And declaration of whatever is used as its ItemsSource. The `<Button>`: is that part of CollectionView's `ItemTemplate`?

Comment: @Jason to bind SelectedItem, you need to deal with options None/Single/Multi. And after that you need to deal with pretty tricky problems with themes and colors. The amount of extra work you will do is simply not worth the skipping of the passing the clicked item as command parameter. (For delete command, I mean.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a property for `selectedItem` in your view model:

```
public Data selectedItem;
public Data SelectedItem
{
    get
    {
        return selectedItem;
    }
    set
    {
        if (selectedItem != value)
            selectedItem = value;
    }
}
```

Set that property in the view model's constructor:

```
public MyViewModel()
{
    Items = new ObservableCollection<Data>();
    SelectedItem = new Data();
}
```

Then, create a delete method and pass the selected item:

```
public void Delete()
{
    if (Items.Contains(SelectedItem))
        Items.Remove(SelectedItem);
}
```

Finally, bind the selectedItem property of the collection view (XAML):

```
<CollectionView  SelectionMode="Single" SelectedItem="{Binding Source={Reference sideview}, Path=myViewModel.SelectedItem}">
```

When you call the `Delete()` method, the selected item gets removed. For example, I bound a button to this method:

```
<Button Text="Remove selected item" Command="{Binding DeleteCommand}" />
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type viewmodel:MyViewModel}}, Path=DeleteCommand}"
```

To clarify a bit:

You need to be inside of DataType (set to your CollectionView ItemTemplate) to use your:

```
{Binding .}
```

As CommandParameter.

And to be inside of such DataType, requires you to go up one level, so you find the path to your Command in your ViewModel.

Comment: I have two different views my collection is in child view and delete button is in another view. I have updated my code can you please check it once ?

Comment: There is no difference where your collection is. The ItemTemplate is what matters. You have to set your Model as its DataType. Otherwise you cant reference with ".", also I said in the comments that SelectedItem for delete command is bad. I still do not recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code below to delete the item in the collectionview.

In the Mainpage.xaml

```
<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Products}">
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                
                    <StackLayout>
                        <Label Text="{Binding Name}" />
                        <Label Text="{Binding Price}" />
                        <Button Text="Remove" Clicked="Remove_Clicked" />
                    </StackLayout>
                
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>
```

In the Mainpage.xaml.cs

```
  public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            BindingContext = new ProductsViewModels();
        }
        public void Remove_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var button = sender as Button;
            var product = button.BindingContext as Products;
            var vm = BindingContext as ProductsViewModels;
            vm.RemoveCommand.Execute(product);
        }
    }
```

In the ViewModel

```
 internal class ProductsViewModels
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Products> Products
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public Command<Products> RemoveCommand
        {
            get
            {
                return new Command<Products>((Product) => {
                    Products.Remove(Product);
                });
            }
        }
        public ProductsViewModels()
        {
            Products = new ObservableCollection<Products> {
                new Products {
                    Name = "name1",
                        Price = 100
                },
                new Products {
                    Name = "name2",
                        Price = 100
                },
                new Products {
                    Name = "name3",
                        Price = 100
                }
            
            };
        }
    }
```